# mysql update query by post email and client

Tags: php, mysql, forms, input

I do have a problem with my database update: I need to update the database with the data from the form $_post, but it won't updated.

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM newsletter WHERE client = ? AND email = ?";
$sql = $dbp->prepare($query);
$sql->execute(array($_POST["client"], $_POST["email"]));
$count = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if($count["count"] == "0")
{
  $query = "UPDATE newsletter SET tip = 'subscriber' WHERE client = ? AND email = ?";
  $sql = $dbp->prepare($query);
  $sql->execute(array($_POST["client"], $_POST["email"]));
}
echo '<h4>congrats! '.$_POST["email"].'</h4>';
exit;
}
```

And the code for the form that $_POST the data.

```
 <form method="post" action="?">

            <div>
                <div style="display:inline-block;margin-bottom:20px;"><input type="checkbox" name="submit" value="Confirm"  required> <span style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px;">confirm</span></div>
                <div style="display:inline-block;"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Confirm"/></div>
            </div> 
            <input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $_GET["email"]; ?>" />
          <input type="hidden" name="client" value="<?php echo $_GET["client"]; ?>" />
        </form>
```

Comment: You have 2 different inputs with the same name.

Comment: i've changed it, it doesn't work

Comment: There doesn't really seem to be any point in having the SELECT

Comment: See the (new) answer then.

Comment: What happens when you add an `else { echo "Sorry"; }` to `if($count["count"] == "0")
{...}`? Does it go there?

Comment: in fact you want to make an insert if the count == 0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in the logical execution here:

```
if($count["count"] == "0")
{
     $query = "UPDATE newsletter SET tip = 'subscriber' WHERE client = ? AND email = ?";
```

If the count is 0, there is no row to update. You will need to insert when the count is 0. If you want to update, there needs to be a row to update.